# How do I separate a string into different chars

Tags: c

Also after I want to add a key to each letter like 'a' + 1 = 'b'. So I want to take a string for instance "Hello" then do

```
    char 1 = H + 1;
    char 2 = E + 1;
         etc.
        printf("%c" + "%c" + "%c" + "%c" + "%c", 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5);
```

also I would love for this to be automated because IDK how long the string might be and what key theyre are going to use.

Comment: A string is an array of separate chars. All you need to do is loop (e.g. use a `for` loop) and add one to each char. Also variables can't be named `1`, `2`, etc in c.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>


    int main()
    {
        char text[] = "Hello";

         int i=0;
         int size= strlen(text);

         for(i=0;i<size;i++)
         {
              //something here  
         }

         return 0;

     }
```

Comment: Yikes!  That's going to call `strlen` for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is mutable, you can update it in place:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void update(char *s, int delta)
{
    while(*s)
        *s++ += delta;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[] = "Hello";
    update(str, 1);
    printf("Encoded: \"%s\"\n", str);
    update(str, -1);
    printf("Decoded: \"%s\"\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

If the string is immutable, you will need to make a copy of it, and update the copy.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char str[] = "Hello";
    char *copy = strdup(str);
    update(copy, 1);
    printf("Encoded: \"%s\"\n", copy);
    update(copy, -1);
    printf("Decoded: \"%s\"\n", copy);
    free(copy);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should read about dynamic arrays in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* code(const char* message)
{
    int i = 0;
    char* coded;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++)
    {
        coded[i] = message[i] - 3;
    }
    return coded;
}

char* decode(const char* message)
{
    int i = 0;
    char* coded;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++)
    {
        coded[i] = message[i] + 3;
    }
    return coded;
}

int main()
{
    // This is dynamic allocated chars array
    char* message = "Hello World!";
    message = code(message);
    printf("%s\n", message);
    message = decode(message);
    printf("%s\n", message);
}
```

Comment: You never allocate any memory for `coded`, so this code will fail

Comment: In fact, clang on x86_64 just checks if `message[0]` is a `NUL`.  If it is, it returns a garbage value.  If it is not, it executes a `ud2` instruction, which generates an exception.